# Cppcheck: Custom rule for check Comments for all functions

Tags: coding-style, comments, customization, cppcheck

[Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) is the tool which analyses our CPP code. I want to create custom rule for Cppcheck to check whether all functions have comments or not. For that I need a PCRE (Pearl regex) pattern. Or any other predefined rules to address this scenarios.

Comment: And what is your question EXACTLY?

Comment: We can implement this rule for you in PVS-Studio.

Comment: Did you try [doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/index.html)? It's more appropriate for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are some predefined rules available @ installerlocation\cfg, what is the purpose of it? whether we can write rules using it instead of tools?

Comment: You'd better make a comment from this.

Answer (score 0):

I am a cppcheck author. Yes, you can write rules using PCRE expressions. But as far as I know you can't see if there are comments from a rule. As far as I know, all comments and indentation are removed before any rules are executed.

Comment: Is this caused by the tokenizing step that is done before cppcheck applies its rules? May it be possible that there is a "pseudo-token" for comments? Or are comments simply added to the (optional) white-space between tokens? BTW: An early *no* would make it a more pragmatic answer.